# C++ invalid object return semantics

Tags: c++

Couldn't find the answer in any similar-named question.

I want a user to be able to initialize a string member at any point in the lifetime of an object, not necessarily on construction, but I want them to know that the object is invalid until the string is initialized...

When creating a simple class, say the following:

```
#include <string>

class my_class {
  public:

    my_class() : _my_str() { }

    my_class(const std::string & str) : my_class() {
      set_my_str(str);
    }

    std::string get_my_str() const {
      return _my_str;
    }

    void set_my_str(const std::string & str) {
      _my_str = str;
    }

  private:

    std::string _my_str;
};
```

and a user creates an empty instance of the class (i.e. using the empty constructor), _my_str will be an empty/uninitialized string?

So, I see two ways of handling behavior: the way mentioned above, where an empty string is returned, or a possible second way:

```
#include <string>

class my_class {
  public:

    my_class() : _my_str(), _my_str_ptr(nullptr) { }

    my_class(const std::string & str) : my_class() {
      set_my_str(str);
    }

    std::string * get_my_str() const {
      return _my_str_ptr;
    }

    void set_my_str(const std::string & str) {
      _my_str = str;
      _my_str_ptr = &_my_str;
    }

  private:

    std::string _my_str;
    std::string * _my_str_ptr;
};
```

Where you return a nullptr, and you maintain a pointer to a local variable?

Is that valid behavior? Which way is preferred and why? Wouldn't the second way be better since you are telling the user, "listen, this object is currently invalid, you need to initialize it" while still implying that you are managing the lifetime of such object.

Comment: When you're returning a non-const pointer you are definitely not implying that you are managing the lifetime of an object.

Comment: BartoszKP, my mistake. Looks like my topic is getting roasted. This is a question that always plagues me when writing classes :| Overseeing that, why is it preferrable to return an empty object over a null pointer?

Comment: Without knowing the purpose of this class, how can we know which option is better? Better for what? The generic name doesn't help.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley are you implying that the second way is a valid way of handling this? If so, why don't you see it used in standard library classes, ever, like vector or string?

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera Why not just returning a const reference to your member?

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera: Handling what? When you design a class, you design it because you want to use it for something. You don't just apply some generic design principles and expect  it to be useful.

Comment: Part of the problem with handing around a pointer is there is always the risk of some tool `delete`ing it. Other than that, My classsss! My claaaaassssss! Filthy hobbitses stole my class!

Comment: @BenjaminLindley well, I tried to make it generic to separate my particular concerns from the general way of doing things, but my particular use case is writing a class that represents a variable name in an equation. The string holds the name, and there are other member variables to represent other properties of an equation variable.

Comment: In the case described your class are responsible for telling the user that a member of the class is invalid, but the user may want to  decide if it is valid or not to use, if your class can give this information then you should create another method, if the class can't return the string if it is invalid then you can throw an exception or just return an empty string(keeping the method to tell that is invalid), your approach is valid too, but more hard to maintain(i think)

Comment: @BenjaminLindley hence the use case: there is not variable name without a string to hold the actual name. Everything else in the class is invalid if there is no "name" string.

Comment: @user2542813 The thing is, I want a user to be able to initialize the string later on, not necessarily on construction, but I want them to be able to know that the object is invalid until the string is initialized...

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera: This exists: `std::optional<std::string>`.

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera Change the 'valid/invalid' for 'initialized/uninitialized' then, i think will help you. Also you could use a boolean flag(if you dont want to use the pointer) and return it in another method

Comment: The std::optional seems a good approach too

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera Why do you need to distinguish these situations actually? Sounds like an XY-problem design flaw for me (hence the _"drive by downvotes"_, don't justify before improving your question why you would need that actually).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> _my_str will be an empty/uninitialized string?

Empty, yes. Uninitialized, no. It's completely initialized (to an empty string).

> Where you return a nullptr, and you maintain a pointer to a local variable?
>
> Is that valid behavior?

Yes it's valid, but

> Which way is preferred and why? Wouldn't the second way be better since you are telling the user, "listen, this object is currently invalid, you need to initialize it" while still implying that you are managing the lifetime of such object.

It makes absolutely no sense to maintain two distinct member variables for this. It sounds like what you need is [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional) (or the equivalent in Boost, [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html)), so that `_my_str` has two states: empty/invalid (contains no string) and non-empty/valid (contains a string):

```
#include <string>
#include <experimental/optional>

using std::experimental::optional;

class my_class {
  public:

    my_class() /* default-initializes _my_str as empty */ { }

    my_class(const std::string & str) : _my_str(str) { }

    const std::string * get_my_str() const {
      if (_my_str) // if it exists
        return &*_my_str; // return the string inside the optional
      else
        return nullptr; // if the optional is empty, return null
    }

    /* Or simply this, if you don't mind exposing a bit of the
       implementation details of the class:
    const optional<std::string> & get_my_str() const {
      return _my_str;
    }
    */

    void set_my_str(const std::string & str) {
      _my_str = str;
    }

  private:

    optional<std::string> _my_str;
};
```

If `""` (an empty string) can be used as a [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) to signify the "empty/invalid" state in your case, then you can just do this:

```
#include <string>

class my_class {
  public:

    my_class() /* default-initializes _my_str as "" */ { }

    my_class(const std::string & str) : _my_str(str) { }

    const std::string * get_my_str() const {
      if (!_my_str.empty()) // if it'a non-empty
        return &_my_str; // return the non-empty string
      else
        return nullptr; // if it's empty, return null
    }

    void set_my_str(const std::string & str) {
      _my_str = str;
    }

  private:

    std::string _my_str;
};
```

Comment: It would be fun to know why this deserves a downvote.

Comment: tuple_cat, agreed. A lot of drive-by-downvoters on stackoverflow...
To simplify my question:

I want a user to be able to initialize the string later on, not necessarily on construction, but I want them to be able to know that the object is invalid until the string is initialized...

Comment: Didn't downvote, but `get_my_str` should probably just return `const optional<std::string>&`...

Comment: @tuple_cat: Also, there's no reason for `my_class`. OP should just use `optional<std::string>` directly.

Comment: @MooingDuck Maybe, I put it up there as an alternative. And yes, if the whole class is this then `optional<std::string>` should just be used directly.

Comment: @tuple_cat, is `optional` used a lot? Reason I ask is because this scenario is one that seems to come up a lot in my coding...

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera Right now, not as often as it should, since it's not officially in the standard yet (will be in C++17). But any non-trivial project will have to deal with an optional class, be it `std::experimental::optional`, `boost::optional`, `llvm::Optional`, or whatever.

Comment: @tuple_cat Ok, how do people usually deal this using <=c++11? I didn't put it in the topic, but it is a requirement in my project. I will accept this answer anyway.

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera Using Boost.

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera: If this scenario comes up a lot in your coding then you could also think about the design. "Optional" values may come in handy at times but in general it is -imho- preferable to design in a way that values will be created in a "valid" state when required. Variable scope should be as small as possible.

Comment: @Pixelchemist I am using optionals more as a an alternative to immutability. Say a class that can contain 3, mutually-exclusive different kinds of members. With optionals it becomes easy to check what kind of member it contains of the 3, without having to resort to inheritance and type-checking. And inheritance wouldn't apply to these 3 different types because it would violate LSP.

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera I'm not a drive-by downvoter. I downvoted because initially, the code in this answer didn't even compile and contained poor advice. Now, I still don't like it (e.g. returning `optional<std::string>` is not exposing details in this case - it's a good, clear and readable representation of contract of this class, no matter what is inside), but at least it works, so I've removed the downvote. Don't judge if you don't know for sure who's downvoting and why - there is no obligation to explain yourself on SO :-)

Answer (score 2):

1. An empty `std::string` value is not per definition invalid. It is just empty.
2. On important difference is that the second "get_..." approach does not copy the object but gives the user a non const pointer to the internal string which leads to violation of const correctness since you imply that the class may not be changed by having `const` at the get method while still providing a pointer that may change the internal state.
3. If your logic implies that "empty string" == "invalid" and if this is a possible state there is not much of a difference whether the user must do

   - `if (get_my_str())) // use valid pointer to nonempty string` versus
   - `if(!get_my_str().empty()) // use valid nonempty string`

I think.

4. You'd want to return `std::string const &` from your get method and leave it to the user wether to copy the object or not.

   4.1. No forced copy (versus by value return `std::string`)

   4.2. No pointer which may be nullptr and accidentally dereferenced.

   4.3. Passing around and storing a pointer which may outlive the object is more common that dangling references.

---

> I want a user to be able to initialize the string later on, not necessarily on construction, but I want them to be able to know that the object is invalid until the string is initialized...

The question is: Is an empty string actually a "valid" value after proper initialization?

- If yes: use `optional` to add one additional state signaling validity.
- If no: let the emptyness of the string stand for invalidity of your object.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the pattern you're referring to is called [*Null object*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) pattern.

The "oldest way" of implementing it was using one of possible values of a variable and reserving it for "no value" meaning. In case of a string an empty string commonly was used in such a way. Obviously not always possible, when all values were needed.

The "old way", was always using a pointer - (`const T* get_t() const`). This way the whole range of variable values could be meaningful, and still "no value" semantics were available by means of returning a null pointer. This was better, but still pointers are not as comfortable to use, not safe. Nowadays, pointers are usually bad engineering.

The modern way is [`optional<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional) (or [`boost::optional<T>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html)).

Comment: THANK YOU! I was looking for the name of this pattern.

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera In that case, you might also want to look into [option type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type) - but I'm guessing you've probably found this already by now ;)